# AWS API Gateway HTTP API custom domain with VPC Link to ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up an API using a REGIONAL custom domain that routes HTTP requests to ALB.
The domain is registered with another DNS provider so I will not be using Route53.

Concept:
`/path/to/service` --> ALB (Listener: `/path/*`) --> ECS

I first tried with the original invoke URL `https://cuxxxxmvk0.execute-api.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/path/to/service`, it returns ALB context path error (It's expected because ALB gets `/stage/path/to/service` which doesn't hit any prefix).

Then I created a custom domain with API mapping (no base path) that maps to the stage, and try invoking it with the provided "API Gateway domain name" (The one generated by custom domain). `Full URL: https://d-yjexxxds3.execute-api.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com/path/to/service`
However, it returns `{"message":"Not Found"}`

[API Gateway domain name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvTC.png)

---

So my question here is:

How does the "API Gateway domain name" generated by custom domain works? Can I directly invoke the API with it?

Is it a must to CNAME it (i.e. `CAME api.mydomain.com d-yjexxxds3.execute-api.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com`)?

Can I make my final endpoint to be `api.mydomain.com/path/to/service` without the stage in path?

Answer (score 0):

From the question I can see that you're trying to use **CNAME** to resolve to URL/some/path but that's not how it works. DNS service will only map your CNAME to some other URL only. The path (/some/path) part will remain same from your domain or API-GW URL.

Other thing to note here is that since you're not using Route53, you do **not** need `Custom Domain Name` of API-GW. Create a CNAME which is something like
`example.com` *CNAME* `d-yjexxxds3.execute-api.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com`

I would suggest you add `/stage` in your ALB prefix so that it can be accessed by API-GW and your own domain.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It was a mistake in the question, I meant to `CNAME api.mydomain.com d-yjexxxds3.execute-api.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com`

I wanted to use api.mydomain.com/path/to/service instead of api.mydomain.com/stage/path/to/service as the final endpoint actually.

Answer (score 0):

> How does the "API Gateway domain name" generated by custom domain works? Can I directly invoke the API with it?

Yes, you can

> Is it a must to CNAME it (i.e. CAME api.mydomain.com d-yjexxxds3.execute-api.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com)?

It is either CNAME (when the DNS is managed by an external provider) or it can be ALIAS (directly returning A  records if you manage the DNS in Route53). Please note you need a validated certificate in the certificate manager.

> Can I make my final endpoint to be api.mydomain.com/path/to/service without the stage in path? 
> https://d-xxxxxxds3.execute-api...

As far I know you should invoke the API by defined custom domain name (api.mydomain.com). If calling the `d-..` domain will work, I'm not sure

`https://api.mydomain.com/path/to/api`

I'm not sure what is not working in your setup. Indeed in the custom domain mapping you can have a mapping directly to certain stage, so you may invoke the API as `https://customdomain/path/to/api`  We have it working this way.

Long story short, your setup / idea is generally good. You may enable logging on the API Gateway or stage to find out what is not working (if the NOT FOUND is retuned by the API GW or backend ELB)